# BizTalk NSoftware SFTP - Read first file only when second file received

Tags: biztalk, sftp, correlation, sequential, adaptor

I have a scenario where client drop an XML and a .FINISHED file. Client create the .FINISHED file once it’s finishes writing XML file. Both file have same name. As you can see, I can’t start reading .XML before .FINISHED created. Once XML copied to target I like to delete both files from the client location.

It looks very typical problem but I think SFTP and SSO have made it non-typical.

I am developing on BizTalk 2009 using /n software SFTP Adaptor for BizTalk with SSO for authentication.

**Notes:**

- I have to use SFTP as I can’t use FTP protocol.
- There are some solutions I have Googled and tried but all are FTP
  based and/or using Correlation.
- I have to use SSO for managing credentials.
- software SFTP Adaptor provides the feature to use SSO and it is working fine under normal scenario where I have to read/write without waiting for .FINISHED file.

I have used following approaches:

**Correlation – Parallel/Sequential**

- After spending some time I realised that I can’t use Correlation as I
  have to wait for .FINISHED file before start reading .XML. Client
  starts writing XML first and then FINISHED
- When I drop the .XML receive location picks the file without waiting for .FINISHED and Orchestration through exception depending
  upon situation.

  For this solution I have got help from following blog

  http://www.paulvanbrenk.com/blog/CategoryView,category,BizTalk.aspx

Please correct me if I have wrong understanding.

**Using a .Net Component to Get the XML File from SFTP location once .FINISHED received:**

- I see this as solution but I am having issues getting file from SFTP
  site.  I have to use SSO for authentication and can’t find any .NET
  based SFTP solution using SSO.

  For this solution I have got help from following site:

  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/biztalkgeneral/thread/29938f2f-ba45-4f5d-bb4c-3dfab4c9bd3e

**Another possible solution** is to change Software or any other SFTP Adaptor’s receive location or URI within Orchestration at runtime i.e. initially set it to .FINISHED once received change it to .XML and get it.

Don’t know how to achieve it but is it possible within orchestration??

Answer (score 3):

Another option with the /nsoftware SFTP adapter is to use the MonitorFileGrowth setting.

This records the size of a file between polling intervals and won't try to download the file until it has stopped increasing (so the file is no longer being written to). You can set it in the Other property of the adapter like:

> MonitorFileGrowth=true

Or if you have control over the process that creates the files on the server using a temporary extension for the file that doesn't match your FileMask (so the receive location won't try to download it) would also work.

Or if you want to wait for the .FINISHED file like Fabio said, you could configure the receive location to only look for .FINISHED files, and once received in your orchestration use the send adapter to download the XML file as per this article: http://www.nsoftware.com/kb/showentry.aspx?entry=09170901

Comment: Thanks. I can't use “MonitorFileGrowth” because of client requirement. Can you please explain in detail how can I use the approach you guys have specified in this article: http://www.nsoftware.com/kb/showentry.aspx?entry=09170901 I mean, should I create two receive ports, one active for .FINISHED and other non-active for .XML? When and where will I set following properties? before receiving the .XML file on the second receive port in Construct Message shape?: Message_2(nsoftware.BizTalk.SFTP.RemoteFile) = "*.txt"; Detailed response will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set your receive location to only activate on files that end in .FINISHED. Then write your orchestration to go and fetch the corresponding XML file - could that work?

Comment: Fabio, that's the second option I tried and mentioned in question. To do this I need to write .NET component using SFTP protocol and SSO for authentication. Can you please guide me to get this done? Any third party component or library that allows SFTP file download using SSO. OR. any work arround. Thanks

Comment: You said your SFTP adapter provides the feature to use SSO, why do you need a .NET component? All you need is to set a mask for the  file you want to download, i.e *.FINISHED - does your adapter not support that?

Comment: Yes it does support. Let me rephrase my scenario. When client start writing XML file I can’t read. Once copy completed it created a .FINISHED file. I've created a receive location for .FINISHED. In my Orchstrtn I'm checking if .FINISHED file received then get the .XML file. But I don’t know how to get the .XML using SFTP and SSO. Should I get it through a custom/third party .Net compnt or a SFTP Adptr? I think I need .Net cmpnt to read .XML file as Adptr can only read through receive-port. You said “Then write your orchestration to go and fetch the corresponding XML file”. What does it mean?

Comment: Could you have an orchestration with two receive ports, the first for the .FINISHED file and the second for the XML? Not sure if this would work, you would have to specify the filename for the second port at runtime, e.g. using a promoted property. Did you try that?

Comment: Like Spencer said, you can use the send adapter to download a file on demand (not receive as I suggested above). You will need to specify the nsoftware.BizTalk.SFTP.RemoteFile promoted property to specify the name of the file that corresponds to the .FINISHED file that activated the orchestration instance. Hope it's clear, have fun!

Comment: Thanks Fabio but I dont know how to use/create solicit response port within an orchestration that will allow me to download XML fiel? Will I get the file within Orch. and I need to send to the Send Port? Please elaborate. Regards

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560470.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577447.aspx) might help...